# When updated, JLabel changes order and comes to the front

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to make a visual novel using Java Swing, and so far it has been going smoothly.  I'm using a JLabel that is attached to a JPanel to make the background image, and it starts good: [image of a background behind a textbox + choice buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfBV6.png), but when I try to update the image using Game.backgroundLabel.setIcon(newBackground);, it brings the background label to the very front: [image of a background in front of the textbox, with only one of the three buttons showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYOUs.png).  I'm new to the entirety of Java Swing, and mediocre at Java, but I'll try to include only the code that I believe to be relevant.

FROM THE MAIN CLASS (Game.java):

```
Container con;
JPanel backgroundLabel;
JLabel backgroundLabel;
```

```
// Creates background
backgroundPanel = new JPanel();
backgroundPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);

backgroundLabel = new JLabel();

backgroundPanel.add(backgroundLabel);
con.add(backgroundPanel);
```

FROM A DIFFERENT CLASS (Story.java):

```
ImageIcon inCarBackground = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\kiwid\\eclipse-workspace\\FatuiBusiness\\backgrounds\\inCarBackground.png");
ImageIcon scaraSprite = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\kiwid\\eclipse-workspace\\FatuiBusiness\\sprites\\ScaraSprite.png");
```

This first update works, and the JPanel stays in the back where I added it in the Game.java class, as shown in the first image.

```
public void gameStart() {
position = "inCar00";
Game.nameLabel.setText("");
Game.mainTextArea.setText("My name is Lumine.  I’ve recently sided with the Fatui - a huge mafia\norganization - through Scaramouche, who I befriended in Teyvat\nUniversity.  I’m on a mission for the Fatui to steal a Blue Diamond\nring that once belonged to the Tsaritsa herself."); 
        
Game.backgroundLabel.setIcon(inCarBackground);
        
Game.choice1.setText("");
Game.choice2.setText(">");
Game.choice3.setText("");
}
```

However, this update seems to change the order of the JPanel, and brings it to the front of the screen.

```
public void inCar01() {
position = "inCar01";
Game.mainTextArea.setText("Here with me are Tartaglia, Scaramouche, and Mona.  Or, as I’m\nsupposed to call them here, Childe, Balladeer, and the Prophesizer.");
    
Game.backgroundLabel.setIcon(scaraSprite);
}
```

I've searched online for a solid 2 hours, but can't find anything good.  I've read a little bit about JLayeredPane, but it seems like that revolves around user input, and when I try to use it, it says that I cannot add a JPanel to it.

Thank you all so much in advance!  Please tell me if there's any other code I need to include, or if there's any code that I did not need to include (so I know for the next time I need help here).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. The code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Comment: .. 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 4) `Game.mainTextArea.setText(..` implies either a poorly named instance of `Game` or a static `mainTextArea`. Don't do either. In the first case .. Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: You either use a background panel or a background label, but not both. If you want the label as a background then you need to set the layout of the label and add components to the label and get rid of the panel. If you want to use a background panel then you paint the image on the panel and add the components to the panel and get rid of the label. See: [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your comments - @AndrewThompson, my variables were static, and I've changed the code so that they aren't anymore.  At the time of writing, it seemed like a simple way to get the variables over to another class - I've fixed this and learned why I can't just "static" any variable I want to directly manipulate in another class.  I also do indent my code, I was just taking snippets of code, and it looks like the indentation didn't make its way through.

Comment: @camickr, Thank you for the Background Panel link!  I had no idea that you wouldn't want to use both.